# Connect 2 jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to connect 2 jQuery functions to one button in html. Where in the code do you put it? I have tried this code, but it creates two results, based on the two onclick functions (?).

```
<div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="App.sellArticle(); App.sellArticle2(); return false;">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to call two functions on a single event? Can't you call second function inside the first one?

Comment: new one function & call your function in it  & put new function in onclick event.

Comment: Vinit Divekar I'm a novice, can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```js
class App {
  static sellArticle() {
    alert('sell article codes');
  }
  static sellArticle2() {
    alert('sell article2 codes');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="App.sellArticle(); App.sellArticle2();">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

```js
class App {
  static sellArticle() {
    alert('sell article codes');
    this.sellArticle2();
  }
  static sellArticle2() {
    alert('sell article2 codes');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="App.sellArticle();">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

I assumed you are using OOP approach.

Comment: Thank you David, Unfortunately, this did not work in my code. I'm trying to simply run two functions with one onClick because I had to declare one variable in my Solidity contract in a separate function, to avoid "stack too deep" errors. Any help in how to do this I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

example like ?

```js
function callA(){
  console.log('A is done!');
}

function callB(){
  console.log('B is done!');
}

//new one

function callAll(){
 callA();
 callB();
 return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="callAll();"> click me.</a>
```